# How do you use break in php 5.4 after it lost its ability to receive variables?

Tags: php, foreach, break

The php manual states under 'Changelog for break':

**5.4.0     Removed the ability to pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; break $num;) as the numerical argument.**

I have a function that copies a table with a tree structure to another table.
After copying each record, the function tests a relation to see if that record has more child records in the next "level" of the tree.

If child records are found, this same function is executed for each child record using a foreach() loop. If they also have child records, the process is repeated, etc. etc.

So the number of "branches" and "levels" in the table will determine how many foreach() loops will be executed. Since the user creates the records, I have no control over the number of "branches" and "levels" in the table.

If *break* cannot receive a variable any more (I cannot run "branch" and "level" counters any more) - how do you break out of ALL loops if an error occurs?

Scaled down example:

```
public function copyTreeModels($row, $id)
{
    try
    {
        /* copy current record. */
        $status == 'ok';

        /* loop to this same function if $status == 'ok' and hasChildren */
        if($status == 'ok')
        {
            If ($row['hasChildren'] == 'yes') // check relation
            {
                foreach($row['children'] as $child)
                {
                    $this->copyTreeModels($child, $id);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            //  break;
            throw new CDbException($message);
        }
    }
    catch(CDbException $e)
    {
        $message .= $e->getMessage();
    }
    return($message);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to make detailed suggestions without seeing the code. But my guess is that you just need to write this as a recursive function, and return through the recursions.

Comment: And for error handling, use `try`, `catch`, and `throw`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar. Wouldn't that waste a lot of time - continue going through all the recursions when you already have an error?

Comment: I did use try, catch and throw - but it then just return to the higher loop. I will try a second throw inside the catch.

Comment: You should only have the `try` at the top level, not every level.

Comment: I added a scaled down example. After catch it goes to return. But, then it goes back to $this->copyTreeModels($child, $Id); Obviously back to another loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `try` in the recursive function. You need a wrapper function around the whole thing that establishes the condition handler:

```
public function copyTreeModels($row, $id) {
    try {
        $this->copytreeModelsRecurse($row, $id);
    }
    catch(CDbException $e)
    {
        $message .= $e->getMessage();
    }
    return($message);
}
```

`copyTreeModelsRecurse` would then be your `copyTreeModels` function, but without the `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: Yeehaa, @Barmar that seams to work. Obviously my function resulted in try/catch statements for all foreach() loops. My exception thus only stopped the most inner loop. Many thanx man.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to set a variable which determines whether or not to break all.

An example (untested) is

```
$break_all = false;
foreach($values as $val) {
    foreach($val as $val1) {
        foreach($val1 as $val2) {
            if($val2 == "xyz") {
                $break_all = true;
            }
            if($break_all) break;
        }
        if($break_all) break;
    }
    if($break_all) break;
}
```

I'll agree with the fact it's not a pretty solution however.

**Edit:**

An alternative suggestion if the amount of nested loops to `break;` from is a variable amount is setting a counter and decrementing the break counter for each break, and only breaking if it is greater than 0:

```
$break_count = 0;

foreach($values as $val) {
    foreach($val as $val1) {
        foreach($val1 as $val2) {
            if($val2 == "xyz") {
                $break_count = 3;
            }
            if($break_count > 0) { $break_count--; break; }
        }
        if($break_count > 0) { $break_count--; break; }
    }
    if($break_count > 0) { $break_count--; break; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan. Thanx for comment. (Was not me that downvoted.) I added a small example. As you can see, the function is re-called an unknown number of times. So I cannot use a fixed number of nested foreach() statements. How would you tackle this?

Comment: Maybe because it's not recursive. He needs to copy a tree of arbitrary depth, you can't hard-code the loops. In fact, this code doesn't need a variable break level, you can just put `break 3` in the innermost loop.

Comment: @GerhardLiebenberg - using the second example in my answer, couldn't you increment the `$break_count` for each loop. And use something like `if($error && $break_count > 0) { $break_count--; break; }` in your loop?

Comment: I suppose I would have to do something like that - having each loop break 1; But would that not be a waist, because you would still have to loop through all the records - even if you had an error on the first record.

Comment: Why would you? If you broke out it would terminate the loop

Comment: Yes it would terminate that single loop, but the tree could have many other branches and levels which would continue. Remember, you could have multiple nested foreach() loops - each having multiple more. Breaking only one of them will not break ALL the others. Anyway, Barmar pointed out why my exception does not stop ALL loops. Thank you for your input.

Comment: No worries - think I got the wrong end of the stick completely. I'll refrain from answering similar questions in future... ;)

Comment: Don't refrain. Your wrong end of the stick maybe had a totally new perspective. That's how we learn.